# How to use Atlassian Document Format in create issue rest api

Tags: jira-rest-api

I am trying to create an issue via Jira API -

```
{
    // other fields is here
    description: {
      type: "doc",
      version: 1,
      content: [
        {
          type: "text",
          text: summary
        }
     }
}
```

but I get an error - "Operation value must be a string".

so how can I create an issue correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're using API version `2` - which accepts **text** for this field.

However, you're providing value as **json** ([Atlassian Document Format](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/apis/document/structure/#atlassian-document-format)) which is for API version`3`